# How to pop navigation controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to try to push a view controller on the stack but I want it to be animated up from the bottom. This is how i do it:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:readerViewController];
[[self.navigationController topViewController] presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and I try to pop it like this:

```
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

for some reason the pop does nothing...

Any idea how to make it go backwards?

The reason i create a new navigation controller btw is that if I don't do this the navigation bar doesn't show not sure why.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're presenting the view controller modally: this is different from *pushing* it on the view controller.

To make "pop" (the proper terminology here is dismiss) this modal view controller, you would call the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` method on `self.navigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the modalview

```
[self presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:NO];
```

and when you want to didmiss this use it

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```